# Displaying footer on second page using Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

How do I set up a Crystal report so that a set document always prints on the even pages and the page header and details for each unique record always print together on the odd pages?

I have a set of instructions that completely fills a page and I need it to always print on the second page of my report.  My report consists of Page Header and Details section, both which always fill one page.

I have the instructions set as the Report Footer and my report prints as I want it to when I have just one record.  (Page header and details on page 1 and instructions on page 2).

Problem is when I have 2 (or more) records - 
Record 1 prints on pg 1
Record 2 prints on pg 2
Header from record 2 prints on pg 3 with the start of the instruction document
Instructions carry over onto next page, again with the header

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use paging concept in section Expert. Select New Page After option in particular section. If you split the same section in multiple parts, you have to checked the check box called Keep Together under common tab in section expert.

OR

Repeat the same Header (RHa, RHb, RHc etc) & introduce sub report as detail section & apply the same concept of paging & new page after particular section.